# SqlAlchemy: Convert datetime column to date column

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to convert the     `datetime` column to     `date`

```
def filter_between_dates(query, req, db_col):

    date_from = req.get_param('date_from')
    #date_to = req.get_param('date_to')

    query = query.filter(cast(db_col,DATE) == date_from)

    return query
```

The error showed: `"name 'DATE' is not defined"`
I tried adding     `import DATE`, and got
    `"ImportError:cannot import name 'DATE'"`

Maybe I'm doing this wrong from the beginning. Please guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to import it.

```
from sqlalchemy import Date, cast
...
def filter_between_dates(query, req, db_col):

    date_from = req.get_param('date_from')
    #date_to = req.get_param('date_to')

    query = query.filter(cast(db_col,Date) == date_from)

    return query
```

Or you can do it with func:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
...
query = query.filter(func.date(db_col) == date_from)
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was importing Date in 
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import desc, or_

Turns out sqlalchemy.sqlexpression is not the same as sqlalchemy. :D